# A user control appearing twice on same page needs unique div id for javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have javascript displaying a message within a div. I pass in an ID and that's how it knows where to display the message.

These div's are within a User Control that appears multiple times on a page. 
The message is only displaying on the first div (as it's the first matching ID. INamingContainer doesn't help me here as the javascript still scans the entire page and finds the first matching ID.

What's the best way around this? Do I have to dynamically set an ID for each UserControl? Is there a way I can have multitple message div's and just enable/disable them from the UserControl code behind to control which ones are shown in each UserControl?

Javascript

```
function ShowMessage(message, messagetype, id) {
var cssclass;
switch (messagetype) {
    case 'Success':
        cssclass = 'alert-success';
        break;
    case 'Error':
        cssclass = 'alert-danger';
        break;
    case 'Warning':
        cssclass = 'alert-warning';
        break;
    default:
        cssclass = 'alert-info';
}
$(id)
    .html('<div id="alert_div" style="margin: 0; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px #999;" class="alert fade in ' + cssclass + '"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>' + messagetype + '!</strong> <span>' + message + '</span></div>');

$(id)
    .fadeTo(4000, 500)
    .slideUp(800,
        function () {
            $(id).slideUp(500);
        });
```

}

And within my UC

```
   <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div>
                                <div class="messagealert alert alert-small" id="spec_gv_alert">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And how the javascript is called from the code behind

```
        Protected Sub ShowMessage(message As string, messageType as string, alertId As string)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                            "ShowMessage('" + message + "','" + messageType + "','" + alertId +
                                            "');", True)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Panel Server control. ASP.Net makes sure that all server controls have unique id.

*For example,*

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" CssClass="messagealert alert alert-small">
</asp:Panel>
```

Rendered HTML

```
<div id="Panel1" class="messagealert alert alert-small">
</div>
```

Comment: How do I pass the unique panel ID to the javascript from the UserControl code behind? So IF(IsStabilityTest) ShowMessage("blah", Error, PanelID) I won't know the ID until it's generated, right?

Comment: Which part do you need? I think all the related code is in the question.

Comment: I think `Panel1.ClientID`. *For example,*  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowMessage('" + message + "','" + messageType + "','" + Panel1.ClientID + "');", True)`

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you Win, you've made a young man very happy.